# Phone number not getting retained in react-phone-input-2

Tags: reactjs, validation, npm, phone-number, npm-package

I'm trying to retain a phone number after button click in react.

The package used here is npm react-phone-input-2

```
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2';
<PhoneInput />
```

After entering a phone number, I'm clicking on next which takes to password page.

[image]

After coming into password page, I'm going to click on back button which redirects to phone number input page.

[image]

But after returning to the phone number page, the entered values is not getting retained.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state variable and store it into local storage when next button click, whenever go back get value from a local store.
e.g.:

```
localeStore.setItem('phone',value);// set value to locale storage
localeStore.getItem('phone');// get value from locale storage
```